# Disable fn-keys for bluetooth keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard

I know that there's a setting to change this behaviour, but it doesn't work for my EasyAcc  bluetooth keyboard.
If this behaviour is known, does it apply to all not-built-in keyboards or all bluetooth keyboards?

**EDIT:**
The setting I'm referring to is:

> Use all F1, F2 etc keys as standard function keys

It doesn't have any effect on my bluetooth keyboard.
I also tried [Palua](http://www.molowa.com/mac-os-x/palua/palua-3-0/) which also only works on my built-in keyboard.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. Are you saying that you have set the Keyboard System Preference to `Use all F1, F2 etc keys as standard function keys` but this setting is being ignored by your BlueTooth keyboard?

Comment: Tony: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem across any number of BlueTooth keyboards designed for iOS when you use them on a Mac. I tested three and all have the same problem.

Attempting to fix it is difficult if not impossible since some testing with my favourite key code tool, [Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/), shows that the OS is intercepting the keypresses before it gets to the keyboard system.

It's not a BlueTooth problem as two different BlueTooth keyboards designed for a PC allowed the setting to work. For example, the [Shintaro Mini](http://www.shintaro.com.au/products/06_keyboards_mice/keyboards/SHBKB/index.php) I use with my Mini media centre works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I have ordered a bluetooth keyboard now. It's too small anyway...